# Jetty server stops or crashes after some time

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, jetty-9, jetty-8

In my project we are developing SFTP, MQ and web service using Spring and Apache Camel. Project is running in Jetty 9. We are using slf4j + logback API for logging. Sometimes my server crashes (stops), I don't know why. It happens frequently after 1 or 2 days of running. I couldn't get much log from my log file.

1. Why server could automatically stop or crash?
2. How to debug it?
3. How to get server log details?
4. How to monitor this issue?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I edited your question. Thanking people in advance in your question is redundant, it just pollutes the question, as well as asking for "kindly help you" (who the hell teaches everyone that uncanny phrase, anyway?). Make sure your question contains only stuff that is required to answer it. Also please start your sentences with a capital letter.

Comment: Please specify the version of Camel, Spring and Jetty9.

Comment: Camel version  2.12, Spring : 3.4 jetty server : 9

Answer (score 0):

If it stops without logging anything you're probably running out of some resource like filehandles, memory, or threads. Or maybe CPU. Get a profiler like YourKit and monitor it for a while. See what's going up.